# Adding a Button to VUE datatables

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I looking to add a button to each row in a datatable component in VUE 2

Currently data is feeding from axios request as per below

```
axios.get('workers/viewall').then(response => this.workerslist = response.data);
```

Added a prop in the Datatable.vue to give customButtons = True

```
 customButtons: {
            default: true
        },
```

And added the below to my Vue file

```
customButtons: {
            hide: false,
            icon: 'search',
            onclick: function (user_id) {
                this.$router.push({
                    name: 'edit_worker',
                    params: {user_id: user_id}
                });
            },
        },
```

Which is put into the data component here:

```
data: function () {
         return {
            workerslist: [],
```

and then column data is as follows:

```
columndata: [{
                label: 'ID',
                field: 'id',
                numeric: true,
                html: false,
            },{
                label: 'First name',
                field: 'fname',
                numeric: true,
                html: false,
            }, {
                label: 'Surname',
                field: 'sname',
                numeric: false,
                html: false,
            }, {
                label: 'Date of Birth',
                field: 'dob',
                numeric: false,
                html: false,
            }, {
                label: 'Gender',
                field: 'gender',
                numeric: true,
                html: false,
            }, {
                label: 'Trade',
                field: 'trade',
                numeric: false,
                html: false,
            }, {
                label: 'Nationality',
                field: 'nationality',
                numeric: false,
                html: true,
            }, {
                label: 'Telephone',
                field: 'telephone',
                numeric: false,
                html: true,
            }, {
                label: 'Mobile',
                field: 'mobile',
                numeric: false,
                html: true,
            }, {
                label: 'Created',
                field: 'created_at',
                numeric: false,
                html: true,
            },{
                label: 'Edit',
                field: 'edit',
                numeric: false,
                html: true,
                }],
```

It just has to put a button to have a click through at the end of each row

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your form? What is the relationship between your `workerslist` attribute and your edit field? It might be as simple as `deleteWorker(worker.id)`...

Comment: That is the form , it just hits a method I should change it to @click:(worker.id) but that is it , its just a click thorough button

Comment: Sorry, you will need to provide a minimal example, as I cannot even figure out which "vue datatable component" you are referring to.